# Set Up the TCP IP Stack of Harmony Configurator on MPLab X IDE

Tags: c, rtos

I've added the TCP/IP Stack on my Harmony Configuration, however it gives me the error below. My question is how to properly set up the TCP/IP Stack on MPLab X IDE V3 with  MPLAB® Harmony Integrated Software Framework v1.04.01.

Error when trying to run the code:

```
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/drivers/usart.c:81:19: error: 'U3MODE' undeclared here (not in a function)
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/drivers/usart.c:81:40: error: 'U3STA' undeclared here (not in a function)
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/drivers/usart.c:81:60: error: 'U3TXREG' undeclared here (not in a function)

nbproject/Makefile-tcp_ip.mk:693: recipe for target 'build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/28866467/usart.o' failed
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/drivers/usart.c:81:82: error: 'U3RXREG' undeclared here (not in a function)
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/drivers/usart.c:81:104: error: 'U3BRG' undeclared here (not in a function)
make[2]: *** [build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/28866467/usart.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

"/opt/microchip/xc32/v1.34/bin/xc32-gcc" -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32MX460F512L -ffunction-sections -O1 -D__XC \
    -I../src -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework -I../src/system_config/tcp_ip/framework -I../src/system_config/tcp_ip -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/bsp/pic32mx460_pim+e16 -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MPLAB/PIC32MXI../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/include \
    -MMD -MF build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/682004257/system_debug.o.d -o build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/682004257/system_debug.o ../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_debug.c

"/opt/microchip/xc32/v1.34/bin/xc32-gcc" -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32MX460F512L -ffunction-sections -O1 -D__XC -I../src \
    -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework -I../src/system_config/tcp_ip/framework -I../src/system_config/tcp_ip -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/bsp/pic32mx460_pim+e16 -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MPLAB/PIC32MXI../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/include \
    -MMD -MF build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/1577513309/tcpip_manager.o.d -o build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/1577513309/tcpip_manager.o ../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/tcpip_manager.c

"/opt/microchip/xc32/v1.34/bin/xc32-gcc" -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32MX460F512L -ffunction-sections -O1 -D__XC -I../src \
    -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework -I../src/system_config/tcp_ip/framework -I../src/system_config/tcp_ip -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/bsp/pic32mx460_pim+e16 -I../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MPLAB/PIC32MXI../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/include \
    -MMD -MF build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/682004257/system_command.o.d -o build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/682004257/system_command.o ../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.c


nbproject/Makefile-tcp_ip.mk:699: recipe for target 'build/tcp_ip/production/_ext/682004257/system_command.o' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myworkarea/HttpTester/firmware/HttpTester.X'
nbproject/Makefile-tcp_ip.mk:78: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myworkarea/HttpTester/firmware/HttpTester.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
In file included from ../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.c:46:0:

../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:49:21: error: redefinition of typedef 'SYS_CMD_HANDLE'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:251:21: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_HANDLE' was here
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:83:2: error: conflicting types for 'SYS_CMD_API'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:370:2: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_API' was here
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:95:2: error: conflicting types for 'SYS_CMD_DEVICE_NODE'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:489:2: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_DEVICE_NODE' was here
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:103:2: error: conflicting types for 'SYS_CMD_DEVICE_LIST'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:510:2: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_DEVICE_LIST' was here
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:109:15: error: conflicting types for 'SYS_CMD_FNC'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:559:15: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_FNC' was here
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:116:2: error: conflicting types for 'SYS_CMD_DESCRIPTOR'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:580:3: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_DESCRIPTOR' was here
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/tcpip/src/system/system_command.h:124:2: error: conflicting types for 'SYS_CMD_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE'
../../../../microchip/harmony/v1_04_01/framework/system/command/sys_command.h:602:3: note: previous declaration of 'SYS_CMD_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE' was here
```

Answer (score 1):

The "redefinition" error happens because two header files are included that define the same typedefs.
The conflicting files are:

```
...\v1_04_02\framework\system\command\sys_command.h
```

and

```
...\v1_04_02\framework\tcpip\src\system\system_command.h
```

which is included by the file

```
...\v1_04_02\framework\tcpip\src\system\system_command.c
```

The file system_command.c is included only if the Harmony component "TCPIP Stack -> Use TCP/IP Commands" is included and "Services -> Command -> Use Command Processor System Service" is not included.

To remove the conflict (and the errors), either disable "TCPIP Stack -> Use TCP/IP Commands", or enable "Services -> Command -> Use Command Processor System Service" (I do not know what this component is for, but if you enable it the code grows about 30 kbytes).

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Actually, I want to create a TCP/IP Client application using the Explorer 16 Dev't Board with Ethernet PICTail and PIC32. So what I want to do first is to properly set up the TCP/IP, SPI and ENCX24J600 DRIVER to make the Ethernet PICTail work and for our router to identify its IP address.

 May you please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Since you will use the Explorer 16 Dev Board, I suppose that you will use the "Microchip Libraries for Applications". In the TCPIP\DemoApp folder of the libraries, there are many ready-made configurations for various development boards and various Ethernet hardware. One of them must suit your needs.

Comment: To define your IP address, you must edit the file "TCPIPConfig.h" and change the constants "MY_DEFAULT_IP_ADDR_BYTEX" (and the other relevant constants too). These demos have by default the "Auto-IP" flag enabled, thus when you run the demo, your board will take IP address from your DHCP server. After that, you may use the Microchip "TCPIP Discoverer.jar" utility to show to you the IP address of your board (this utility is installed with the application libraries).

Comment: I'm sorry I should have told you that I'm using the PIC32MX460F512L. The "Microchip Libraries for Applications (MLA)" is only  compatible with PIC8 and 16. 

I already used the "tcpip_tcp_client" but I wan to start from scratch. I added the TCP/IP Stack on my project without any problem however there are so many errors when I added the ENCX24J600 and SPI driver.

Comment: Thanks George Vassilakis for helping me out. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like some header file, available in two different locations, are both being included.

The multiple guard code in each header file should have stopped that from happening.

Also, it looks like the header file that defines the registers in UART 3 is missing.